# XAMPP stackman_launcher has a different IP address

Tags: xampp, localhost, xampp-vm

When starting XAMPP i suddenly got a new IP address. Instead of 192.168.64.2 I got 192.168.64.3. I have been looking for answers everywhere without a good advice what to do.

The biggest issue is that I can't go to my files that are on the 192.168.64.2. So what am I doing wrong or what solution is there to make XAMPP start next time on a specific IP address. I have also tried to make it start as localhost when changing in httpd.conf to Listen 127.0.0.1:80 without success!

I have also seen that some are saying that I might have xampp-vm. But as far as I know that should not be the issue.

[image]

Comment: I hope to get an answer soon from anybody. I'm desperat to find a solutions so I can retrieve my files from XAMPP!   PLEASE.  !